# How to get a row of unique values from prior row followed by nulls till the next value?

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates, distinct-values

I have a query that has multiple joins and fields. I have one row that has alot of duplicates. I need to only get the distict values from this specific row while leaving the size of the query the same due to the other joins.

I have tried group by and districts but they eliminate other critical information in the query. I need to leave the query length the same.

example:(pseudocode)

```
SELECT
 Name
,StateID
,Age
,Toy
,ManufactureName
From
 peopleTable as people
 LEFT JOIN toyTable on people.id = toytable.id
 LEFT JOIN ManufactureTable on toyTable.toyId=ManufactureTable.ManId
WHERE
 toytable.id >1000
```

output

```
Name   StateID Age  Toy    Manufacture
Carlo  1       10   Woody  Disney
Sid    1       10   Buzz   Disney
Abby   1       10   Car    RaceMan     
Bobby  4       10   Doll   Barbie
Sally  6       10   Book   Barns&
Jim    6       10   Woody  Disney
```

ExpectedOutput

```
Name   StateID Age  Toy    Manufacture NewField
Carlo  1       10   Woody  Disney      1
Sid    1       10   Buzz   Disney      NULL
Abby   1       10   Car    RaceMan     NULL
Bobby  4       10   Doll   Barbie      4
Sally  6       10   Book   Barns&      6
Jim    6       10   Woody  Disney      Null
```

Comment: Please include the primary keys each table has.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this help?

Using `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function, find out the first row in a group of those that share the same `stateid`. Note that I used `order by null` as I don't know which one is the first (`name` isn't, nor is `age` or `toy` or `manufacture`). If you don't care, leave it as is. If you know how to sort them, use that column.

```
SQL> with test (name, stateid, age, toy, manufacture) as
  2    (select 'Carlo', 1, 10, 'Woody', 'Disney'  from dual union all
  3     select 'Sid'  , 1, 10, 'Buzz' , 'Disney'  from dual union all
  4     select 'Abby' , 1, 10, 'Car'  , 'RaceMan' from dual union all
  5     select 'Bobby', 4, 10, 'Doll' , 'Barbie'  from dual union all
  6     select 'Sally', 6, 10, 'Book' , 'Barns&'  from dual union all
  7     select 'Jim'  , 6, 10, 'Woody', 'Disney'  from dual
  8    )
  9  select name, stateid, age, toy, manufacture,
 10    case when row_number() over (partition by stateid order by null) = 1 then stateid
 11         else null
 12    end new_field
 13  from test;

NAME     STATEID        AGE TOY   MANUFAC  NEW_FIELD
----- ---------- ---------- ----- ------- ----------
Carlo          1         10 Woody Disney           1
Sid            1         10 Buzz  Disney
Abby           1         10 Car   RaceMan
Bobby          4         10 Doll  Barbie           4
Sally          6         10 Book  Barns&           6
Jim            6         10 Woody Disney

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```